# Issue with TextView in android

Tags: android, textview, screen-orientation

I am having an issue with my TextView. I have a PlayScreenActivity that displays supplies info. on the top of screen. then I go to the store screen and buy supplies. when I come back all others change but 1 and it will display the new value if I turn my phone and orientation changes, thats the only way I can see the added supplies purchased. Anyone have an Idea why this is happening?

I set screen orientation to portrait to see if it will work if it can't switch but doesnt fix.

EDIT

Here is a copy of my Activity Code:

public class PlayscreenActivity extends Activity {
    Data data_;

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lemonsLeftText)).setText(
            "Lemons: "  );
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.sugarLeftText)).setText(
            "Sugar: "  );
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.iceLeftText)).setText(
            "Ice: "  );        
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.cupsLeftText)).setText(
            "Cups: "  );
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.btnshop)).setOnClickListener(
            new SupplyShopListener());
}
private class SupplyShopListener implements OnClickListener{
      public void onClick(View v){
          Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), SupplyShopActivity.class);
          startActivity(i);
          //refreshDisplay();
      }
```

}

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    data_ = getData();
    refreshDisplay();
}

@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    saveData();
    refreshDisplay();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    //refreshDisplay();
}

private Data getData() {
    GameData player_data = new GameData(this);
    player_data.open();
    Data game_state = new Data(player_data.getGameString());
    player_data.close();
    return game_state;
  }

private void saveData() {
    GameData player_data = new GameData(this);
    player_data.open();
    player_data.setGameString(data_.SerializeGame());
    player_data.close();

}
private void refreshDisplay() {

    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
    String totalCash = nf.format(data_.cash_);

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.lemonsLeftText)).setText(
            "Lemons: "  + Integer.toString(data_.lemons_) );        
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.sugarLeftText)).setText(
            "Sugar: "  + Integer.toString(data_.sugar_) );
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.iceLeftText)).setText(
            "Ice: "  + Integer.toString(data_.ice_) );
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.cupsLeftText)).setText(
            "Cups: "  + Integer.toString(data_.cups_) );
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.totalCashText)).setText(
            "Cash : "  + (totalCash) );

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...it will display the new value if I turn my phone and orientation changes

Android will destroy and re-create the activity when run-time configuration changes occur. It makes sense that your new variables are being drawn on screen rotation, because the entire activity is re-created:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

If most of your TextView widgets are updating when your PlayScreenActivity is resumed, your refreshDisplay() call is working (to a degree). Which widget doesn't redraw? I'd also throw in some logging and watch the LogCat like zapl suggested.

**EDIT**

Sample code with some logging (I moved the widgets into fields...)

```
public class PlayscreenActivity extends Activity
{
    Data data_;

    String TAG = "PlayScreenActivity";

    TextView lemonsLeftTextLabel;
    TextView sugarLeftTextLabel;
    TextView iceLeftLabel;
    TextView cupsLeftTextLabel;
    TextView totalCashTextLabel;
    Button shopButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d(TAG, "Creating PlayScreen activity...");
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Log.d(TAG, "Assigning buttons...");
        lemonsLeftTextLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lemonsLeftText);
        sugarLeftTextLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sugarLeftText);
        iceLeftLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.iceLeftText);
        cupsLeftTextLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cupsLeftText);
        totalCashTextLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalCashText);

        shopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnshop);

        lemonsLeftTextLabel.setText("Lemons: ");
        sugarLeftTextLabel.setText("Sugar: ");
        iceLeftLabel.setText("Ice: ");
        cupsLeftTextLabel.setText("Cups: ");

        shopButton.setOnClickListener(new SupplyShopListener());
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() complete");
    }
    private class SupplyShopListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v){
            //Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), SupplyShopActivity.class);
            //startActivity(i);
            refreshDisplay();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        Log.d(TAG, "onResume() called");
        super.onResume();
        data_ = getData();
        Log.d(TAG, "Data fetched");
        Log.d(TAG, "Contents of data = " +
                "Lemons: " + Integer.toString(data_.lemons_) + " | " +
                "Sugar: " + Integer.toString(data_.sugar_) + " | " +
                "Ice: " + Integer.toString(data_.ice_) + " | " +
                "Cups: " + Integer.toString(data_.cups_) + " | " +
                "Cash: " + data_.cash_ + " | ");

        refreshDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        Log.d(TAG, "onPause() called");
        super.onPause();
        saveData();
        refreshDisplay();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        Log.d(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged() called");
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    private Data getData() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getData() called - restoring");
        GameData player_data = new GameData(this);
        player_data.open();
        Log.d(TAG, "Pulling data from game string...");
        Data game_state = new Data(player_data.getGameString());
        player_data.close();
        Log.d(TAG, "Contents of data = " +
                "Lemons: " + Integer.toString(game_state.lemons_) + " | " +
                "Sugar: " + Integer.toString(game_state.sugar_) + " | " +
                "Ice: " + Integer.toString(game_state.ice_) + " | " +
                "Cups: " + Integer.toString(game_state.cups_) + " | " +
                "Cash: " + game_state.cash_ + " | ");
        return game_state;
    }

    private void saveData() {
        Log.d(TAG, "saveData() called - saving");
        GameData player_data = new GameData(this);
        player_data.open();
        Log.d(TAG, "Serializing data into GameData object");
        Log.d(TAG, "Contents of data = " +
                "Lemons: " + Integer.toString(data_.lemons_) + " | " +
                "Sugar: " + Integer.toString(data_.sugar_) + " | " +
                "Ice: " + Integer.toString(data_.ice_) + " | " +
                "Cups: " + Integer.toString(data_.cups_) + " | " +
                "Cash: " + data_.cash_ + " | ");
        player_data.setGameString(data_.SerializeGame());
        player_data.close();

    }
    private void refreshDisplay() {
        Log.d(TAG, "refreshDisplay() called - redrawing UI");

        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
        nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        String totalCash = nf.format(data_.cash_);

        lemonsLeftTextLabel.setText("Lemons: " + Integer.toString(data_.lemons_));
        sugarLeftTextLabel.setText("Sugar: " + Integer.toString(data_.sugar_));
        iceLeftLabel.setText("Ice: " + Integer.toString(data_.ice_));
        cupsLeftTextLabel.setText("Cups: " + Integer.toString(data_.cups_));
        totalCashTextLabel.setText("Cups: " + totalCash);

    }
}
```

Comment: Well I ran the catlog for Sugar and I pu a log in both the shop activity and the playscreen. when I click the button to buy sugar I have a refreshTotal in that activity that shows total purchased amount before I accept and go back to playscreen. It shows that my data_.sugar_ gets the 12 but doesnt have it once it goes back to playscreen

Comment: Well, I'm not sure about the Data and GameData objects, but you're choosing to create a new GameData object in saveData(), and then you're passing it the entire activity, which seems a bit excessive. If you only want to persist the data, try passing a Bundle instead? 

Also, you could try using onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() to  actually persist a full object. Doesn't really persist it beyond memory, but it might be a useful alternative?

http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2009/02/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: I got it working. It was something with my serialized data and how sugar wasnt paired up with the others

Answer (score 0):

You update the textviews at the wrong place maybe. 
Or call `textview.invalidate()` after you change them - that's usually not required but might be if there was no user interaction at the time they change.

Comment: But I have 3 other textviews that change/update and they change just fine. I am using a refreshDiplay(); in onResume

Comment: I even tried to move around the TextViews in the xml design and the never moved when I re-ran my program

Comment: If you add some `Log.d("TAG", "total cash should display: " + totalCash);` etc to your `refreshDisplay()` does it really show the updated values? I can see no error in your code.

Comment: Everything shows updated values on regular orientation except for Sugar. But when I turn phone it displays correctly, then I turn phone back and it goes back to Sugar: 0 , And what is wierd is that when I change around the textviews in the layoutdesign they don't switcharound when I run the app

Comment: if you reorder them in the layout then they have to do the same in your app (or are you using relative layouts and position them based on each other?) - if not then the xml is maybe not saved, or the app not re-installed correctly. Your sugar problem is most probably that you forgot to save or load that one. `onResume`, `onPause` is called everytime you rotate the device

Comment: Yeah, Well not sure if I figured out was wrong but if the app is closed then opened back up and then sugar shows , but if start new game and try to buy supplies, it doesnt show anymore

Comment: Well I ran the catlog for Sugar and I pu a log in both the shop activity and the playscreen. when I click the button to buy sugar I have a refreshTotal in that activity that shows total purchased amount before I accept and go back to playscreen. It shows that my data_.sugar_ gets the 12 but doesnt have it once it goes back to playscreen